# parsing complex xml with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, csv

I try to parse a xml but no chance for me, if someone can explain how can i do or explain where is the problem i 'd be grateful:

Here my xml code:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <nvd xmlns:vuln="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4" xmlns:scap-        core="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1" xmlns="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cpe-lang="http://cpe.mitre.org/language/2.0" xmlns:patch="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1" xmlns:cvss="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2" pub_date="2013-01-22T06:34:06" xsi:schemaLocation="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/patch/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/patch_0.1.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/scap-core/0.1 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/scap-core_0.1.xsd http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0 http://nvd.nist.gov/schema/nvd-cve-feed_2.0.xsd"         nvd_xml_version="2.0">
      <entry id="CVE-2009-0001">
        <vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
          <vuln:product>cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:3</vuln:product>
          <vuln:product>cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:7.3.1.70</vuln:product>
        </vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
        <vuln:cvss>
          <cvss:base_metrics>
          <cvss:score>9.3</cvss:score>
          <cvss:access-vector>NETWORK</cvss:access-vector>
          <cvss:access-complexity>LOW</cvss:access-complexity>
          <cvss:authentication>NONE</cvss:authentication>

          </cvss:base_metrics>
          </vuln:cvss>
      </entry>
      <entry id="CVE-2009-0002">
        <vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
          <vuln:product>cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:3</vuln:product>
          <vuln:product>cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:6.5</vuln:product>
          <vuln:product>cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:7.0</vuln:product>
          <vuln:product>cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:7.3.1.70</vuln:product>
        </vuln:vulnerable-software-list>
        <vuln:cvss>
          <cvss:base_metrics>
            <cvss:score>3.2</cvss:score>
            <cvss:access-vector>NETWORK</cvss:access-vector>
            <cvss:access-complexity>LOW</cvss:access-complexity>
            <cvss:authentication>NONE</cvss:authentication>

          </cvss:base_metrics>
        </vuln:cvss>
      </entry>
    </nvd>
```

I use xslt with the xsl file below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                    xmlns:nvd="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0"
                    xmlns:vuln="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="text" />

    <xsl:template match="/"><xsl:apply-templates select="nvd:nvd" /></xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="nvd:nvd"><xsl:apply-templates select="nvd:entry" /></xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="nvd:entry">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="vuln:vulnerable-software-list">
      <xsl:with-param name="entryid" select="@id" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="vuln:vulnerable-software-list">
    <xsl:param name="entryid" />
    <xsl:for-each select="vuln:product">
    <xsl:value-of select="$entryid" />:<xsl:value-of select="text()" /><xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is :

```
    # xsltproc a2.xsl a2.xml
    CVE-2009-0001:cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:3
    CVE-2009-0001:cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:7.3.1.70
    CVE-2009-0002:cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:3
    CVE-2009-0002:cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:6.5
    CVE-2009-0002:cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:7.0
    CVE-2009-0002:cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:7.3.1.70
```

But now i want to add the cvss:score a the end like this:

```
    CVE-2009-0001:cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:3@9.3
    CVE-2009-0001:cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:7.3.1.70@9.3
    CVE-2009-0002:cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:3@3.2
    CVE-2009-0002:cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:6.5@3.2
    CVE-2009-0002:cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:7.0@3.2
    CVE-2009-0002:cpe:/a:apple:quicktime:7.3.1.70@3.2
```

I have try somethink like this :

adding

```
          <xsl:apply-templates select="vuln:cvss/cvss:base_metrics/cvss:score">
```

or

```
    select="*/score"
```

but it doesn't work .... :-(

of course i have add a parameter :

```
      <xsl:value-of select="$score" /><xsl:text>
```

in the template vuln:vulnerable-software-list

Thanks for your help

Regards

Arno

---

Hi Jallopa: i have try to add your code in for-each section but it return this :

```
    xsltproc a.xsl a.xml
    XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
    xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed
    runtime error: file a.xsl line 21 element value-of
    XPath evaluation returned no result.
```

Line 21 contains:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::entry[1]/vuln:cvss/cvss:base_metrics/cvss:score"/>
```

Hi wst , i have try your code but this time

```
    xsltproc a.xsl a.xml
    XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
    xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed
    runtime error: file a.xsl line 15 element with-param
    Failed to evaluate the expression of variable 'score'.
```

line 15 is :

```
           <xsl:with-param name="score" select="vuln:cvss/cvss:base_metrics/cvss:score"/>
```

(i have add = in your select in with-param)

Any Ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Within the foreach element, add:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::entry[1]/vuln:cvss/cvss:base_metrics/cvss:score"/>
```

this will navigate up the tree to the first "entry" element, then down to the cvss:score.

Answer (score 0):

This problem could be solved a little more simply, but keeping your template style, you can just pass the value as another parameter:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:nvd="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/feed/vulnerability/2.0"
    xmlns:vuln="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/vulnerability/0.4" version="1.0">

<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:apply-templates select="nvd:nvd" /></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="nvd:nvd"><xsl:apply-templates select="nvd:entry" /></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="nvd:entry">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="vuln:vulnerable-software-list">
        <xsl:with-param name="entryid" select="@id" />
        <xsl:with-param name="score" select"vuln:cvss/cvss:base_metrics/cvss:score"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="vuln:vulnerable-software-list">
    <xsl:param name="entryid" />
    <xsl:param name="score" />
    <xsl:for-each select="vuln:product">
        <xsl:value-of select="$entryid" />:<xsl:value-of select="text()" />@<xsl:value-of select="$score" /><xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi jaloopa, i have try to add your code in for-each section but it return this :  ` xsltproc a.xsl a.xml
XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed
runtime error: file a.xsl line 21 element value-of
XPath evaluation returned no result.` and hi wst , i have try your code but this time ` xsltproc a.xsl a.xml
XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed
runtime error: file a.xsl line 15 element with-param
Failed to evaluate the expression of variable 'score'. (i have add = in your select in with-param) Any Ideas ? Thanks

Comment: @user2033272 I looks like the namespace for prefix `cvss` is not declared. Try adding `xmlns:cvss="http://scap.nist.gov/schema/cvss-v2/0.2` to the stylesheet with the existing namespaces.